# Ubuntu 18.04 VM crashed hosted on Azure

Tags: 18.04, crash, azure

Ubuntu VM with 18.04 OS version hosted on Azure, crashed and unable to access in serial console as well. Had to force restart the VM to get the access again.

No logs reported during the crashed time...Logging happened after VM came up post reboot.

Saw below highlighted after the crash:

```
Jan 24 14:56:43  kernel: [3393495.154433] audit: type=1400 audit(1611500203.578:1363716): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="docker-default" pid=6593 comm="process-agent" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
Jan 24 14:56:43  kernel: [3393495.154438] audit: type=1400 audit(1611500203.578:1363717): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="docker-default" pid=6593 comm="process-agent" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
Jan 24 14:56:43  kernel: [3393495.154442] audit: type=1400 audit(1611500203.578:1363718): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="docker-default" pid=6593 comm="process-agent" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
Jan 24 14:56:43  kernel: [3393495.154445] audit: type=1400 audit(1611500203.578:1363719): apparmor="DENIED" operation="ptrace" profile="docker-default" pid=6593 comm="process-agent" requested_mask="read" denied_mask="read" peer="unconfined"
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  **Jan 24 15:58:28  systemd-modules-load[442]: Inserted module 'iscsi_tcp'
Jan 24 15:58:28  systemd-modules-load[442]: Inserted module 'ib_iser'**
Jan 24 15:58:28  keyboard-setup.sh[453]: cannot open file /run/tmpkbd.aTTaud
Jan 24 15:58:28  systemd[1]: Started Monitoring of LVM2 mirrors, snapshots etc. using dmeventd or progress polling.
Jan 24 15:58:28  systemd[1]: Started Create Static Device Nodes in /dev.
Jan 24 15:58:28  systemd[1]: Started Load/Save Random Seed.
Jan 24 15:58:28  systemd[1]: Mounted FUSE Control File System.
Jan 24 15:58:28  systemd[1]: Mounted Kernel Configuration File System.

Kernel Version: 5.4.0-1032-azure
```